# Prove that $(Z+)^*$ is countable

Tags: set-theory

2 things are given:

1. $(Z+)^n$ is countable for all n
2. If A is countable and B is countable, then $A \cup B$ is also countable

My attempt:

$(Z+)^* = (Z+)^1 \cup (Z+)^2 \cup (Z+)^3 \cup ....... $

Using induction and 1. and 2. above, I can show that $(Z+)^1 \cup (Z+)^2 \cup (Z+)^3 .....\cup (Z+)^k$ is countable for any k.

Is this a valid proof for $(Z+)^*$ is countable. If not, how can this be shown?

Comment: Countable union of countable sets is countable.

Comment: What you are doing does not work, is like saying that $\mathbb{N}$ is finite because for every $k$ the set $\{1,\dots, k\}$ is finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming "$Z+$" means $\mathbb{N}$).

"Countable union of countable sets is countable" (in the comments) is a good proof.

For a more direct proof, you can build an injection $f$ from $\mathbb{N}^*$ to $\mathbb{N}$:$$f(n_1,n_2,\ldots ,n_k)=\prod_{j=1}^kp_j^{n_j+1},$$where $p_j$ is the $j$-th prime number.

One can also use continued fractions. This time the injection is to $\mathbb{Q}$, which is countable too.

Comment: To clarify the injection, the set $(Z+)^*$ will have infinitely long elements right? In those cases, how does f work?

Comment: @bmz I am not familiar with this "*" notation, except if it is the Kleene star, where it means a _finite_ length concatenation. Anyway, if infinitely long elements are allowed, the set is no more countable; the concatenation of an infinite number of digits in [0, 9] is already uncountable (think of the decimal representation of real numbers).

Comment: Yes, it is a Kleene star. I was under the impression, * can have infinite length strings. It makes sense, it its only finite length.

Answer (score 0):

$\{0\}$ is a finite set 
$\{0,1\}$ is a finite set
$\{0,1,2\}$ is finite set
 $
\vdots$

Repeating to infinity gives us that the set of all naturals is a finite set(!)

**So your reasoning is defintely not valid.**

All you can prove using induction is that the union of a **finite** number of countable sets is countable.

To prove the result you want you want, use the fact that the [union of a countable number of countable sets is countable](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Countable_Union_of_Countable_Sets_is_Countable).